# Looking for good book similar Stability/Conditioning in Numerical Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently reading *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau and I am finding it quite difficult to read. In particular, I have been trying to read the sections on Floating Point Arithmetic, Stability, and Conditioning, and they are pretty confusing to me; it has taken me 3-4 hours to go through the four pages on floating point arithmetic, and there are still a couple things I am unclear on.

I am looking for a book which goes over similar material as Trefefthen and Bau, but  which fleshes things out a bit more.

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly one of the best references is the [book by Higham](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718027).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in "Things Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic" : https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf

As for stability / conditioning, these are pretty universal topics in numerical analysis, my recommendation is the next time you're near the library is to just go browse through some books (QA297-299) and see what looks friendly.